# Arduino ESP32 FreeRTOS - How to declare empty byte array in task

Tags: c, arduino, esp32, freertos

I have the following FreeRTOS function:

```
void UARTSendCommand(void *pvParameters)
{
  (void) pvParameters;
  uint8_t receive[];  //***** NEED TO DO A EMPTY ARRAY 
  for (;;) 
    {
      xSemaphoreTake(xCountingSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY);
      xQueueReceive(queue, &receive, 0);
      if(receive)
      {
        Serial.println("UART Send command received");
        uart_write_bytes(UARTNUM, (const char*) receive, sizeof(receive));
      }
      xSemaphoreGive(xCountingSemaphore);
      vTaskDelay(1);
  }
}
```

The Queue is declared as:

```
 UARTSendQueue = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(char));
```

And when I send to queue I do this:

```
byte message[] = {0x5A, 0xA5, 0x05, 0x82, 0x20, 0x00, (gaugeImage >> 8) & 0xFF, gaugeImage & 0xFF };
      xSemaphoreTake(xCountingSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY); 
      xQueueSend(queue, &message, 0);
      xSemaphoreGive(xCountingSemaphore);
```

What I need is to get in my Task function the parameter sent in the queue, but I don't get anything.

Any clue?

Comment: The real question is what are you trying to do here? What condition are you trying to test for? Because the test you're doing certainly isn't doing that correctly. The issue isn't "how to declare an empty byte array", it's "how to test for some condition" properly. It's likely going to be "how to manage memory properly" too.

Comment: Having an empty array doesn't make much sense. And `xQueueReceive` won't make the array bigger. You are basically just causing a buffer overflow.

Comment: Your code won't compile with `uint8_t receive[];` and it will give you an error message like "definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer". To create a receive buffer of 10 bytes and empty it, you need to declare it as `uint8_t receive[10] = {0};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues are meant for sending/receiving one item at a time. You may want to check out the [Stream Buffers](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-stream-buffer-API.html), if you want to send/receive multiple items.

I'm going to assume that you want to queue complete messages, not single bytes and that the length of messages is 8, as per your code.

First, lets update the queue creation code to allocate space for messages, instead of bytes:

```c
#define MAX_MESSAGES 10
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 8
#define MESSAGE_SIZE (MESSAGE_LENGTH * sizeof(char))

UARTSendQueue = xQueueCreate(MAX_MESSAGES, MESSAGE_SIZE);
```

You seem to be using a semaphore to guard the queue access, but this is not necessary. To send the data, simply do:

```c
xQueueSend(UARTSendQueue, message, 0);
```

On the receiving end, you need to specify the size of the array. Empty array does not make any sense here. You should also check the return type of [`xQueueReceive()`](https://www.freertos.org/a00118.html) to see if the data has been received:

```c
uint8_t message[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
for (;;) {
    BaseType_t received = xQueueReceive(UARTSendQueue, message, 0);
    if (received) {
        ...
```

Note that I have removed `&` from `message`, as `message` is an array and it decays to pointer automatically.

---

**Edit**

In case of variable message lengh and where there are multiple senders, the simplest approach is to allocate the message buffer dynamically and to queue the pointer to allocated memory.

To create a queue:

```c
#define MAX_MESSAGES 10
#define MESSAGE_SIZE sizeof(char*)

UARTSendQueue = xQueueCreate(MAX_MESSAGES, MESSAGE_SIZE);
```

To send a message:

```c
uint8_t *message = (uint8_t *)pvPortMalloc(messageSize)
// Populate the message with the data here.

// Using portMAX_DELAY here to avoid memory leak.
// If message must be dropped, free the memory.
xQueueSend(UARTSendQueue, &message, portMAX_DELAY);
```

To receive the message:

```c
uint8_t* message;
for (;;) {
    BaseType_t received = xQueueReceive(UARTSendQueue, &message, 0);
    if (received) {
        // Process the message
        // Free the memory
        vPortFree(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this looks pretty clean. My only problem is that message[MESSAGE_LENGTH] is variable. There are messages with 8 bytes and other with 10 or 12. Any clue how to manage this? Appreciate so much

Comment: @VAAA is there one sender and one receiver?

Comment: there could be multiple Senders. Only one receiver. Thats why I just added a Mutex on the uart_write_bytes to avoid any concurrency conflict.

Comment: @VAAA answer updated.